# Drive.comments.list(fileId).items.length doesn't seem to count correctly

Tags: api, google-apps-script, comments, drive

Just found something peculiar in the Drive Comments API. Not sure if its user error or an issue in the API.

In my main() Logger is putting the length of comments as 20. I go back into my document and create another comment. Logger still puts length of comments items as 20.

Thanks in advance.

```
function main() {
  var fileId = getFileId();
  var fileComments = getComments(fileId);
  Logger.log(fileComments.items.length); // this always says 20  
}
function getFileId() {
  return DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId(); 
}
function getComments(fileId) {
  return Drive.Comments.list(fileId);
  //Logger.log(cmnts.items.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read further on the drive comments list reference and the default page size is 20 per page. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/comments/list